# Converting nested codable objects to dictionaries swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, encodable

I am currently using this extension which works fine for basic objects. I am having a hard time figuring out how to convert nested Codable objects to dictionaries with this call...thanks in advance!

```
public extension Encodable {
  var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by nested dictionaries but it looks like you don't want to return an array of dictionaries. I think what you are looking for is a dictionary where its values are dictionaries. Anyway I will post both options:

```
extension Encodable {
    // this would try to encode an encodable type and decode it into an a dictionary
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [:] }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
    }
    // this would try to encode an encodable type and decode it into an array of dictionaries
    var dictionaries: [[String: Any]] {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [] }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
    }
    // this would try to encode an encodable type and decode it into a dictionary with dictionaries as its value
    var nestedDictionaries: [String: [String: Any]] {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [:] }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: [String: Any]] ?? [:]
    }
    // this will return only the properties that are referring to a nested structure/classe
    var nestedDictionariesOnly: [String: [String: Any]] {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return [:] }
        return ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]).compactMapValues { $0 as? [String:Any] }
    }
}
```

Comment: So for example : if i had a user object with a profile object inside. I want to convert the user object to a dictionary but within that dictionary convert the profile object to a dictionary. 

[“user”: [“profile” : some data]]

Comment: Show your encodable object and the expected output

Comment: struct Example: Codable {
    let nestedExample: NestedExample
    
}

struct NestedExample: Codable {
    let nestedExample: String
}

Expected output

let dict = ["example" : ["nestedExample": "nestedString"]]

Thanks for the help

Comment: I will say this wont work for an object that looks like this
struct Example: Codable {
 let nestedExample: NestedExample
 let samepleString: String
 }

Comment: So what do you want? Do you want to discard those properties? You can also return nil instead of an empty dictionary.

Comment: Check my last edit. It is not clear whats the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: no i want to have a dictionary create that has all properties whether its a nested object which can be converted to a dict and have a key with a string value.

Comment: So you need to return single dictionary

Comment: check my last edit. There is no magic type declaration (other than `[Stirng:Any]`) to decode a `jsonObject` into. You would need to cast the dictionary values from `Any` to the actual types.